# How do I join two tables on one column while preserving the values in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union, full-outer-join

I have two tables.

**links_table**

```
URL                     Links
example.com/1           6
example.com/2           2
example.com/3           4
```

**pages_table**

```
URL
example.com/2
example.com/4
```

How do I combine all the URLs in a way that preserves the number of links?

**Desired result:**

```
URL                     Links
example.com/1           6
example.com/2           2
example.com/3           4
example.com/4           null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can emulate a `full join` with `UNION ALL` and aggregation:

```
select url, max(links) links
from (
    select url, links from links_table
    union all
    select url, null from pages_table
) t
group by url
```

Comment: Perfect, that seems to work. I wish that MySQL had a native `FULL JOIN` function.

Comment: @Pikamander2: yes, unfortunately this is not part of MySQL syntax, as for `lateral join` (aka `cross apply`)...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to return all the rows in `links_table` plus additional rows in `pages_table` that are not in that table.  I would just use `union all`:

```
select l.url, l.links
from links_table l
union all
select p.url, null
from pages_table p
where not exists (select 1 from links_table where l.url = p.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this: (not 100% sure though)

```
SELECT * 
FROM links_table l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pages_table p ON p.url = l.url 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM links_table l 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN pages_table p ON p.url = l.url 
WHERE l.url IS NULL;
```

Comment: SELECT url, links 
FROM links_table
UNION
(
SELECT url, null 
FROM pages_table
MINUS
SELECT url, links 
FROM links_table
)
this?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM links_table l
LEFT OUTER JOIN pages_table p ON p.url = l.url

UNION

SELECT *
FROM links_table l
RIGHT OUTER JOIN pages_table p ON p.url = l.url
WHERE l.url IS NULL;